# passing down state with redux to stacknavigator

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, stack-navigator

I have a react-native App, with react-navigation and redux separated, so i don't pass my navigation property to redux. I set everything up for Redux to work but it seems that my state doesn't get passed on to the screens in the Stacknavigator.

Here is my StackNav.js:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import { HomeScreen } from '../screens/HomeScreen'

export const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
);

export default RootStack;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that i needed to import HomeScreen without curly braces, i guess that's because i call the connect function in the export default and i exported the HomeScreen class, as well as the connected component of Homescreen, so i always imported the unconnected class.

Here is the fixed Code:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen'

export const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
        Card: {screen: CardScreen},
    },
);

export default RootStack;
```